# Adding effects to a flex custom component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, effects

I have a flex application and I want to add a new custom component with action script at runtime.
This works fine. I have created my custom component and added the following code:

```
var freeView:FreeView=new FreeView();
freeView.setStyle("showEffect",this.fadeIn);
freeView.setStyle("hideEffect",this.fadeOut);
freeView.visible=false;
this.addChild(freeView);
freeView.visible=true;
```

But my problem is the fade in effecto is not working. I know I've declared the effect correctly because if I use it in another component (like a panel) it works fine.
Can anybody help me with this issue?
Best regards!

Comment: If you can, provide a bit more information, such as what the parent component looks like. Also, try using the code formatting button in the editor to help make your question more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve the problem in a different way.
Instead adding the component at run time I have added the component to the application with visible property set to false and I change it to true when I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you call any overridden Flex super-functions in your FreeView subclass.

Especially updateDisplayList and commitProperties:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number)
{
    super.updateDisplayList(w, h);

    // Your code here.
}


override protected function commitProperties()
{
    super.commitProperties();

    // Your code here.
}
```

Are you overriding one of the high-level container classes (e.g. Canvas or HBox) or UIComponent?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the other way around by setting effects target to your new element

```
<mx:Fade id="showFlag" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="5000"/>

var flag:Image = new Image;
flag.source = flagSource;

something.addElement(flag);

showFlag.target = flag;
showFlag.play();
```